# How to improve performance with this dictionary of sets built with Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, set, hashtable

Let's say we have 10 millions of socks, and each of them has color `sockcolor[i]` and is stored in `drawer[i]`.
I'd like to count how many *different* colors there are in each of the 20 drawers.

To do this, I used a dictionary containing sets (sets use a hashtable under the hood which is handy to count unique elements).

The following code works, but it's quite slow (~10 seconds for 10 millions of socks).

**How could we use Numpy techniques (vectorization?) or avoid the `for` loop to speed up this computation?**

```
import numpy as np
N = 10*1000*1000
drawer = np.random.randint(0, 20, N)            # 20 drawers
sockcolor = np.random.randint(0, 100*1000, N)   # 100k different colors
d = {}

for i, k in enumerate(drawer):
    if k not in d:  # can be simplified with collections.defaultdict but no gain here
        d[k] = set()
    d[k].add(sockcolor[i])

for k, s in d.items():
    print(k, len(s))
```

Output:

```
16 99323
7 99330
0 99339
17 99364
14 99272
12 99303
11 99334
6 99362
19 99287
10 99282
4 99280
18 99325
3 99316
15 99303
5 99280
13 99357
2 99328
9 99290
1 99293
8 99293
```

Comment: `numpy` is not meant for sets and dictionaries. Can't you organise your data in a simple vector?

Comment: @zvone here sets are used as a tool for deduplication

Comment: But why is `numpy` used? There is no real benefit from it here.

Comment: @zvone because my data comes from numpy arrays in my real use case, so I'd like to avoid converting it to a regular python list because it wouldn't add anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically already have a mapping from drawers to sockcolors, but they are randomised and you want to organise them by drawer number.

The easiest thing to do is to first sort them by drawer numbers:

```
drawer_sort = np.argsort(drawer)
drawer = drawer[drawer_sort]
sockcolor = sockcolor[drawer_sort]
```

Now that they are sorted, there is no need to look for drawer number duplicates, you just have to find the indices at which the drawer numbers change, to form ranges, which are these:

```
changes, = np.where(drawer[1:]-drawer[:-1])
starts = np.concatenate([[0], changes+1])
ends = np.concatenate([changes, [len(drawer)]])
```

Now you can create your dictionary:

```
result = {drawer[start]: sockcolor[start:end] for start, end in zip(starts, ends)}
```

This way, the only itaration done in Python is the last line, which will be really fast if there are a small number of distinct `drawer` values (in your case not more than 20).

The result can still have duplicate `sockcolor` values, but that is easily solved in numpy:

```
result = {drawer: np.unique(sockcolors) for drawer, sockcolors in result.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your slowness comes from failing to use the built-in features of your sequences.  Iterate through the individual socks only once.  Instead, assign the sock colors (not indices of individual socks) to the drawers.  Then make a set from each drawer's contents: one wholesale operation, rather than an incremental `set.add`, which is relatively slow for your purposes.